# Update Reports not available after Upgrade to 4.7.10

Tags: civireport, 4.7.10, display

After Upgrading to 4.7.10 from 4.7.8, it looks like the Reports have lost some of their features. The buttons for Preview Report, Update Report Save as Copy at are not displayed anymore.

Here is the screen before upgrade:

[image: Report screen for v4.7.8]

Here is the screen after upgrade:

[image: Report screen for v4.7.10]

Answer (score 1):

This functionality has been moved to the action drop-down list.
[image]